# SpringBoot 2.2.4 + spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize and spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize not working

Tags: spring-boot

I have to build my application using spring boot 2.2.4 and I have added the following properties to the application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=1024MB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=1024MB
server.connection-timeout=300s
```

Following is my rest endpoint

```
import java.io.InputStream;


import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String create(
    @NotNull @FormDataParam("testFile") InputStream testInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("testFile") FormDataContentDisposition testFileFormDataContentDisposition,
    @FormDataParam("testConfigFile") InputStream testConfigFileInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("testConfigFile") FormDataContentDisposition testConfigFileFormDataContentDisposition,
    @NotNull @FormDataParam("configFile") InputStream configInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("configFile") FormDataContentDisposition configFileFormDataContentDisposition,
    @FormDataParam("testCreateRequest") String request);
```

When I tried to upload more than 1GB file, it successfully uploads this file. No exception occurred even though I have provided maxFileSize and maxRequestSize is 1024MB.

*can someone let me know what is wrong with this*

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. Those are to configure file uploading with Spring, you are using Jax-RS and not Spring, hence those properties don't apply.

Comment: I am getting following error if I will not provide above three properties:
Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: 
The field configFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
What is the alternative to upload file with large size using JAX-RS?

Comment: Apparently they get applied to the container as well now, interesting. The error will only occur after uploading the file, as the file size can only be checked afterwards.